# 2d camera rotation (javascript)

Tags: javascript, camera, rotation, 2d

I'm making a simple 2d javascript engine based on a scene graph (all game objects are containers/nodes and their children live inside their parent's coordinate space).

My camera implementation works by setting up a camera as a root container for the game entities, and setting it up to follow the 'player' child.
Without rotation this works fine - I simply set the camera's position negative to that of the target:

`this.x = -target.pos.x, this.y = -this.target.pos.y`

But when I try to follow the same logic for rotation (`this.rotation = -this.target.rotation`) this fails - the player soon gets out of view.

To clarify - the result I'm trying to achieve is to make the scene rotate around the player when he turns (from a top view), leaving the player always facing the same direction.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

..edit:

how it looks without rotation:
https://gfycat.com/graveforsakencow
with rotation 
https://gfycat.com/cheaptimelyboar

the camera update method :

```
        if (!this.rotation_mode) 
            this.follow();
        else 
            this.followAndRotate(); 

    }

    follow() {
        this.pos.x = -this.target.pos.x;
        this.pos.y = -this.target.pos.y;

        this.pos.x += this.offset_x; //center target on screen
        this.pos.y += this.offset_y;
    }

    followAndRotate() {
        this.rotation = -this.target.rotation;
        this.pos.x = -this.target.pos.x;
        this.pos.y = -this.target.pos.y;

        this.pos.x += this.offset_x; //center target on screen
        this.pos.y += this.offset_y; 

    }
```

Comment: Have you considered the rotational pivot for the camera? eg the coordinates it rotates around, as if it is moving then its pivot may not necessarily be updated

Comment: not sure I know what you mean, I don't think the target position needs to be considered in the camera angle calculation. would it help if i shared some of the code?

Comment: Yes definitely, any code is helpful. Maybe a video, gif or image to help clarify?

Comment: added gifs and the camera update script. you can take a look at the complete source at https://github.com/dimx88/simple-engine but it's a bit messy